# Accessing data from list in python/django

Tags: python

I have this code:

```
list_of_objects = [{
"object": "a",
"object": "b",
"object": "c",
}]

list = []

for objects in list_of_object:
    list.append(objects['object'])

print(list)
```

It only outputs:

`{c}`

I want to display every object on the list
like:
`{a,b,c}`

Comment: Dictionaries can't have duplicate keys. The first (and only) item in `list_of_objects` is a single dictionary with one key. What do you expect `list_of_objects[0]['object']` to actually be? Did you mean to have a list with three dicts like: `[{"object": "a"}, {"object": "b"}, {"object": "c"}]`?

Comment: As @Mark said, you are storing duplicate keys in the dictionary which will result in keeping only the last one as it removes all the previous duplicates.

Comment: oh I missed that, thank you. I'll try it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay as @Mark said in comments, I was using a single dictionary and one key, because each time I declare the object's value it just overwrite the previous.

```
list_of_objects = [{
"object": "a",
"object": "b",
"object": "c",
}]

list = []

for objects in list_of_object:
    list.append(objects['object'])

print(list)
```

The solution is to add curly braces to each object `{object:a},{object:b},{...}`

```
list_of_objects = [
{"object": "a"},
{"object": "b"},
{"object": "c"},
]

list = []

for objects in list_of_object:
    list.append(objects['object'])

print(list)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using a dict incorrectly since dictionaries can only have one value per key. In this situation you just need to use a list:

```
list_of_objects = ["a","b","c"]
```

In case you still want to use a dict for some reason we don't know about, you will have to store an array of objects with the "object" key:

```
list_of_objects = { "objects" : ["a","b","c"] }
```